# How would I call this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Building an Angular app using a football api, the data is loading great, but I'm unsure on how to call the hometeam scorers rather than ALL scorers.

For e.g in the JSON data below it has the 'events' object and inside it has a 'player' property which displays the scorers.

But I want to assign the home and visitor scorers separately.

How do I do this? :)

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <ul ng-repeat="score in scores">
            <li>{{ score.localteam_name}}</li>
            <li>{{ score.localteam_score}}</li>
            <li>{{ score.visitorteam_name}}</li>
            <li>{{ score.visitorteam_score}}</li>
            <li>{{ score.status}}</li>
            <li ng-repeat="scorer in score.events">{{ scorer.player }}</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controller -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/maincontroller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JSON Data

```
[
  {
    "id": "1921980",
    "comp_id": "1204",
    "formatted_date": "03.01.2016",
    "season": "2015/2016",
    "week": "20",
    "venue": "Selhurst Park (London)",
    "venue_id": "1265",
    "venue_city": "London",
    "status": "FT",
    "timer": "string",
    "time": "13:30",
    "localteam_id": "9127",
    "localteam_name": "Crystal Palace",
    "localteam_score": "0",
    "visitorteam_id": "9092",
    "visitorteam_name": "Chelsea",
    "visitorteam_score": "3",
    "ht_score": "[0-1]",
    "ft_score": "[0-3]",
    "et_score": "string",
    "penalty_local": "string",
    "penalty_visitor": "string",
    "events": [
      {
        "id": "21583632",
        "type": "goal",
        "minute": "29",
        "extra_min": 0,
        "team": "visitorteam",
        "player": "Oscar",
        "player_id": "57860",
        "assist": "D. Costa",
        "assist_id": "60977",
        "result": "[0-1]"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: it's not exactly clear what your problem is;  you seem to have all the information you need, though the sample data you provided isn't the best representation of all the possible states you might experience.  It should be simple enough to filter `events.team === 'visitorteam'`; though in this case you only have one event.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes in programming a certain piece of code doesn't have a magic solution and you have to find the right way to do it yourself. If the events array is gonna hold 10-20 objects or so I would strongly suggest you to leave it as is and load all the scorers. If it will be filled up to o(n) and you don't have control on the amount of events added (for example 1000) then there are a two options:

1. If you load the json from the api or receive it from a certain database then you can't change it without iterating through events. This means that if you wanted to iterate through the events array you would pass each one, check if it's the hometown or the visitor and build two new event arrays, homeEvents and visitorEvents. Then replace the original events variable with both of them and you would have perfect control on choosing home or visitor events.
2. If you build that json yourself then build it with homeEvents and visitorEvents instead of the events variable you wanted to use.

Both options basically give you the same solution, number 1 is for when you receive the json as is and number 2 is for when you build it yourself.

Please note this is a general solution, if you are new to angularjs and need help doing that please let me know in the comments and I'll attach a snippet to the code (please let me know if it's number 1 or 2). Good luck!

Comment: Hi Liron, good answer. Yeah I've only been learning Angular about a month so I'm not great yet :D. I'm using an API so I can't change the JSON data. If you have time a code snippet for example number 1 would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ql.soa below me answered with a code, if you don't understand it let me know and I'll add comments or change the code slightly to make it clearer (it's pretty basic I'm sure if you read it twice carefully you'll get it)

Comment: If you could break it down that would be great =D

Answer (score 1):

you can push them into two arrays like this

```
var i, item, j, k, len, len1, ref, ref1, rows;

ref = $scope.scores;
for (i = j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
  rows = ref[i];
  rows.homeEvents = [];
  rows.visitorEvents = [];
  ref1 = rows.events;
  for (i = k = 0, len1 = ref1.length; k < len1; i = ++k) {
    item = ref1[i];
    if (item.team === 'visitorteam') {
      rows.visitorEvents.push(item);
    } else if (item.team === 'hometeam') {
      rows.homeEvents.push(item);
    }
  }
}
```

then in your HTML you can show then with ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="scorer in score.visitorEvents">{{ scorer.player }}</li>
<li ng-repeat="scorer in score.homeEvents">{{ scorer.player }}</li>
```